# OC Command to get all Pods using specific Tag name

Tags: command-line-interface, openshift

I would like to fetch all the Pods in my project using specific tag name. In my project i have 10+ Pods and i have added Tag name like "Rel50" for 5 of the pods.

So i need to fetch those 5 pods names using the Tag name "Rel50".

Please help me with OC Command to fetch those Pods?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `--selector` option to select Pods with a specific label:

```
oc get pods --selector='Rel50'
```